# Limits of quotient groups in the space of marked groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

In the space of marked groups with $m$ generators, suppose that a sequence $(G_i, S_i)$ converges to $(G, S)$. For any $i$, let $K_i$ be a normal subgroup of $G_i$ and assume that $\bar{S}_i$ is the image of $S_i$ in the quotient group $G_i/K_i$. We know that if the sequence $(G_i/K_i, \bar{S}_i)$ converges to a marked group $(A, T)$, then $A=G/K$ for some $K\unlhd G$. My question is this: is it possible to determine $K$ explicitly?

One special example: Let $G_i=\mathbb{Z}_4\ltimes\mathbb{Z}_{2^{i-1}}$ with the action of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ as $a\cdot x=(-1)^ax$. For any f.g abelian group $H$ with $tor(H)=2-group$, the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}_4\ltimes H$ is a limit of $G_i$s. So, there is a marking $S_i$ of $G_i$ and a marking $S$ of $\mathbb{Z}_4\ltimes H$, such that $(G_i, S_i)\to (\mathbb{Z}_4\ltimes H, S)$. For any $i$, let $K_i=\{ 1, (2, 2^{i-2})\}$. We have $G_i/K_i=Q_{2^i}$, the generalized quaternion group. Hence, if $(G, T)$ is a limit of marked quaternion groups $(Q_{2^i}, \bar{S}_i)$, then $G=(\mathbb{Z}_4\ltimes H)/K$ for some normal subgroup $K$. Can we describe this $K$ explicitly?

Comment: In your example, isn't $K$ just the intersection $\bigcap_iK_i$, since you can pass to a nested subsequence?

Comment: @ HJRW. I don't think so, all $K_i$ are two elements, further they are in different groups. It seems that $K$ is very large.

Comment: I think this $K$ is a Sela kernel (or what Sela calls a "stable kernel"). [See here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~zlil/diophantine1.dvi). In the case where $A$ is a free group, $K$ is normally finitely generated. This is a difficult result that deeply relies on the properties of free groups. I don't think there is anything that could be said about $K$ in full generality.